# iPhone App - Show AVFoundation video on landscape mode

Tags: iphone, video, rotation, avfoundation, avcam

I am using the AVCam example App from Apple.

This example uses AVFoundation in order to show video on a view.

I am trying to make from the AVCam a landscape App with no luck.

When screen orientation changes the video is shown rotated on the view. Is there a way of handling this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create your preview layer:

```
captureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
```

And the methods to manage rotations:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
        (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
        duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

  [CATransaction begin];
  if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
  } else {        
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
  }

 [CATransaction commit];
 [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
        (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];

  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Note: you will want to [set the videoOrientation property on the connection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22187500/35690) since the orientation property is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the orientation and gravity settings for the preview layer?

```
previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 300); 
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
previewLayer.orientation =  AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
previewLayer.automaticallyAdjustsMirroring = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
```

in your .h .

Then do:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

in your .m

This will force it to not rotate.