# Landscape in AvCam iOS 6

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, landscape, avcam

I am new to iOS, trying to create custom camera using AvCam. I am having trouble getting landscape orientation preview -- it rotates the view 90 degree clockwise and shows it on a half screen.

I get this message --

> WARNING: -[ setOrientation:] is deprecated.

Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:

AVCaptureConnection already sets orientation, so I have no clue what am I supposed else.

I know this question was asked lots of times for previous versions of iOS (4,5), but non of those techniques/codes worked for me (iOS 6).

Original code (did not make any changes from Apple)

```
if ([self captureManager] == nil) {
    AVCamCaptureManager *manager = [[AVCamCaptureManager alloc] init];
    [self setCaptureManager:manager];
    [manager release];

    [[self captureManager] setDelegate:self];

    if ([[self captureManager] setupSession]) {
        // Create video preview layer and add it to the UI
        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[[self captureManager] session]];


        UIView *view = [self videoPreviewView];
        CALayer *viewLayer = [view layer];
        [viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

        CGRect bounds = [view bounds];
        [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:bounds];

        if ([newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer isOrientationSupported]) {
            [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
        }



        [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

        [viewLayer insertSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer below:[[viewLayer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]];

        [self setCaptureVideoPreviewLayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer];
```

AVCaptureConnection chunk:

```
-(void)startRecordingWithOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)videoOrientation; {
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [AVCamUtilities connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo fromConnections:[[self movieFileOutput] connections]];
if ([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
    [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:videoOrientation];

[[self movieFileOutput] startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[self outputFileURL] recordingDelegate:self];
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Last time i also stumbled upon this issue. I solved this problem by doing two things

1. Getting the right orientation
   Replace

   ```
   if ([newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer isOrientationSupported]) {
       [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
   }
   ```

   With

   ```
   if ([newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.connection isVideoOrientationSupported]) {  
       [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];
   }
   ```
2. Force the update of the video orientation during the initialization to catch video output in landscape mode by triggering
   `- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange` manually within `AVCaptureManager.m`

   I added it to:

   ```
   - (BOOL) setupSession
   {
       BOOL success = NO;

       ...

       AVCamRecorder *newRecorder = [[AVCamRecorder alloc] initWithSession:[self session] outputFileURL:self.lastOutputfileURL];
       [newRecorder setDelegate:self];

       [self performSelector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange)];

       ...

       return success;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

So, here's a workaround, but I am sure that there must be better solution than this. I got part of the code from this question :

[iPhone App - Show AVFoundation video on landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284650/iphone-app-show-avfoundation-video-on-landscape-mode)

But had to adjust frame for every orientation in order to make it work on iOS6 (and it still shows a warning):

---

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                        duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

```
[CATransaction begin];
if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);

} else if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

} else if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);

}
[CATransaction commit];
[super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
```

}

Comment: This thread has a solution for solving orientation warning -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532337/isorientationsupported-is-deprecated-in-ios