# Orientation deprecated in iOS 6

Tags: iphone

Looks like orientation for avcapturevideopreviewlayer has been depreciated in iOS 6. Anyone know the new code? Here is my current (depreciated) code:

```
[self setPreviewLayer:[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[self captureSession]]];
[[self previewLayer] setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
previewLayer.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

Comment: Okey. Thats right. But was is your question? Probably that will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404556/interface-orientation-in-ios-6-0

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you check the documentation? It's only one line:

> The layer’s orientation. (Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Use [videoOrientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureConnection/videoOrientation)
>   (AVCaptureConnection) instead.)

so use:

```
[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer connection] setVideoOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

or

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation= AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

Comment: Tried that. Property 'videoOrientation' not found in object of type 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer'

Comment: 'Cause it's in `AVCaptureConnection`? So, the `connection` property of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.

Comment: I added an example for you:) I hope you don't mind @Nikolai Ruhe

Comment: Shouldn't it be AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight instead of UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight? Both seems to work though.

Comment: This doesn't work - it does not have the same effect as changing .orientation.

Comment: Also: UIInterfaceOrientation* is the wrong type, and although it will sometimes work, you can get problems with e.g. orientations 180 degree flipped

Comment: Note this only works if the AVCaptureSession has been started.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use videoOrientation(AVCaptureConnection) instead of the deprecated orientation(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer), but it did not rotate the video preview anymore.

I replaced this:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = ...;
previewLayer.orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

With this:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = ...;
previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

But it did not rotate the video preview. The problem was that I added and modified the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer before I added the AVCaptureDeviceInput to my AVCaptureSession. Therefore the connection of my AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer was null. The solution was to add the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer after I added the AVCaptureDeviceInput to my AVCaptureSession.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Nikolai posted, use the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer's connection's `videoOrientation` property instead.

(The reason I am posting this again is because his code may be a bit confusing since it looks like `connection` is a class method. Hopefully this example makes it clear.)

Replace the following:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = ...;
previewLayer.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

With:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = ...;
previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
```